# Extracting test data from a generated html file to a xlsx file using selenium java

Tags: java, html, selenium, xlsx

We have loads of tests that runs in 11 different packs. Each pack generates a html file, one with screenshots one without. The goal is to extract the data from the html file (without screenshots) into a xlsx file, this includes the test stage(1,2,3), pass/fail, and execution time. Currently I am manually copying and pasting the data into the xlsx file, and would like to automate it for our nightly builds. if someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult assuming you have some background in Selenium/ Java. You can use Apache POI to enter data into Excel sheets and fetching data from html files can be done using Selenium.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) writing to the HTML file, write to a CSV file and then import that into Excel. I wouldn't write the HTML and then parse it... that seems inefficient at best. If you still want this particular question answered, you will need to post the code you have tried along with error messages and/or why it isn't working.

Comment: I started with Selenium and Java about 8 months ago. This is a new task that was given to me, I have no idea where to start, hence me asking this question. I will start on this project and if I get stuck Ill come back and let you know if I get stuck again. Thanks for the replies